# Isotope Issue with drawers

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have a client who has requested a responsive, staff member grid. The site is built in Wordpress using the Salient theme, and I've hacked it enough to have created a somewhat decent responsive staff grid, with drawers. It's working fine, except for when the user click on the very first tile. It breaks the layout and all other tiles line up horizontally under it. I've changed the layout option several times and have tried everything I can think of, but haven't been able to crack it yet.

http://robertjpotter.com/r-a-a-d/about/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    'use strict';

    setInterval(isotope_relayout,1000);    

});

function isotope_relayout(){

    var $container = jQuery('.masonry_container');

    $container.isotope('layout');

}
```

Comment: For me it works - I check Your demo and masonry display properly after click on some element.